# add navigation back arrow when using ShellContent xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation

When we use `ShellContent` to navigate to Dashboard page for exemple, there is no back arrow in the navigation bar  ?
Any idea how to navigate to dashboard page with possibility to back to previous page ?

```
<Shell ..>
<ShellContent x:Name="home"
IsVisible={Binding IsVisibleHome}
Route="main"
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Dashboard}" />

<ShellContent Route="test"
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Dashboard2}" />

</Shell>
```

Comment: Could you reformulate and clarify the desired behaviour?

Comment: done, my problem when i use Shell.Current.GoToAsync() , it add to the stack, but with ContentTemplate there is no Shell.Current.GoToAsync()  .. there is no stack added

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple built-in way to do this.

Here is one approach, that changes the route to a different one, which isn't accessed as a (ShellContent) child of Shell. This is based on the `AboutPage`, which is part of the "Flyout" project template for Xamarin forms. Replace `AboutPage` with your page, and the route with your route.

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Define a route that isn't a child of Shell.
        Routing.RegisterRoute("about2", typeof(AboutPage));
    }

    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);

        if (args.Current != null) {
            // This line hopefully avoids interfering with Pop, if AboutPage links to another page.
            if (args.Source == ShellNavigationSource.ShellItemChanged) {
                // Replace "//AboutPage" with the route to your page.
                if (args.Target.Location.OriginalString == "//AboutPage") {
                    // Cancel the original route.
                    args.Cancel();
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        // Go there by a route that isn't a child of Shell.
                        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("about2");
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT: Previous shell location is pushed to nav stack. `AboutPage` appears, with a back arrow at upper left of navigation bar.

In other words, the `AboutPage` now behaves like any other page that:

1. Is not defined in the Shell heirarchy - isn't a child of Shell.
2. And has a Route defined.

The "trick" is that we defined a second Route that takes us to the same page. Then we intercepted the original route, and replaced it with this alternate route.

Comment: Agree what u said in other post its daft it works like this to me any navigation away from first page should always post a back button.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution to an annoying problem, sadly it's a lot of boilerplate to manage one route, if you want to make this for more than one route then you have to duplicate this a couple of times (or extract to a method). It also makes the hamburguer menu inaccessible in the second page, which is a bomer. My use case is not exactly OP's, what I wanted to do was to prevent the app from closing when the user navigates to the about page and then taps the physical back button on the phone, this works, but doesn't as I expected.